# manipulating list on jsp page passed from servlet

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

i am reading rssfeeds from a link and filling it in a list in servlet via rome api

```
List<freshbean> allrss = new ArrayList<freshbean>();
RssDao rd = new RssDao();
allrss = rd.getAllRssFromUrl("http://feeds.feedburner.com/GeoBulletins");
request.setAttribute("allrss", allrss);
RequestDispatcher reqdisp = request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/admin/getfeed.jsp");
reqdisp.forward(request, response);
```

On jsp page

```
<c:forEach items="${allrss}" var="post" varStatus="loop">
    <div id=<c:out value="${loop.index}" />  class="container" >

      <div class="row">
            <h1><c:out value="${post.title}" escapeXml="false" /> </h1> 
            <div class="well well-sm"><c:out value="${post.date}" escapeXml="false" /> </div>
            <div class="well well-sm"><c:out value="${post.link}" escapeXml="false" /> </div>
            <c:out value="${post.description}" escapeXml="false" />
    </div>
    <input type="button" id='<c:out value="${loop.index}" />' value='Delete' class="btn btn-danger btn-block"/>                 
    </div>
</c:forEach>
```

now i want to give user an option to delete certain feeds any want to store remaining objects in database.
I've tried this deletion by ajax but when ajax call goes to servlet list allrss is empty

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".btn").click(function() {
        var postid = $(this).attr("id");
        //$(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url : 'RssServlet',
            data : {
                postid : postid
            },
            success : function() {
                $('#' + postid).hide();
                //alert('in success');
            },
            error : function() {
                alert('in error');
            }
        })
    });
});
```

what should be my approach to get the filtered array back on a servlet only with objects which user wants to save

Comment: It's because you store `allrss` as a request attribute, and request is destroyed after rendering the HTML content sent to the browser. The AJAX call runs in another request, then. Store the `allrss` in session.

Comment: Can you share more details on from which object are you trying to delete the list from?

Answer (score 0):

i've solved this problem by making a form in loop and submiting that form data through ajax so user can submit only selected data and leave the remaining on the page.

**on jsp page**

```
    <c:forEach items="${allrss}" var="post" varStatus="loop">
            <form method="post" action="RssServlet" class="form"
              id='<c:out value="${loop.index}" />'>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title">Title:</label> <input type="text"
                  class="form-control" id="title" name="title"
                  value='<c:out value="${post.title}"/>'>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="date">Date:</label> <input type="text"
                  class="form-control" id="date" name="date"
                  value='<c:out value="${post.date}"/>'>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="url">URL:</label> <input type="text"
                  class="form-control" id="url" name="url"
                  value='<c:out value="${post.link}"/>'>
              </div>                  

              <input type='submit' value='Add to database'
                class="btn btn-primary btn-block"
                id='<c:out value="${loop.index}" />'>

            </form>
    </c:forEach>
```

**Ajax on jsp**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".form").on('submit', (function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url : 'RssServlet',
            type : "POST",
            data : form.serialize(),
            success : function(data) {
                alert('in success');
            },
            error : function(e) {
                console.log('Error: ' + e.message);
            }
        })
    }));
```

**Handle the post request in servlet**

```
 String title = request.getParameter("title");
 String date= request.getParameter("date");
 String link= request.getParameter("link");

 Add to database logic
```